# how to show a list of images in scroll view where the images are retrived from the URL XML file in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I can retrieve the images from the XML file of a web server and list the images as scroll view. Now i want to click on a image that should take me to another window where the window should again show some images as a collection view. Can anyone suggest me how to do this.

I listed my TableView Controller and reference image of how i need from the existing.

```
MyTableViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     xmlParser = [[egsXMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://retrieveurlxml.com/sample.xml"];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
   }



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myimages";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        } UIImage *currentTweet = [[xmlParser tweets] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImageView *tweetImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width , cell.frame.size.height)];
        tweetImageView.image = currentTweet;
        [cell setBackgroundView:tweetImageView];
        return cell;
    }
```

My current Scroll view Shows like below,

[image: Current Table view of images scrolling]

How i need is like below,

Can Anyone suggest me how to achieve like this.
 [image: Desired output]

Comment: Can you share me your email address. I'll give you the API which you can use same as adding UIImageView and it'll do everything for you.

Comment: @Rushi ya sure rushi.. This is my mail id - mark.p1274@gmail.com

Comment: Did u get it? I've emailed it to you.

Comment: Yes, i got it. Thank you rushi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the API which i've emailed you. To call this API:

```
ASyncImage *img_EventImag = alloc with frame;
NSURL *url = yourURL;
[img_EventImage loadImageFromURL:url];
[self.view addSubView:img_EventImage]; // In your case you'll add in your TableViewCell.
```

Comment: You had mentioned to add the URL directly to NSURL. As am parsing the images from XML file. Does this API will parse by itself or i have to parse it manually and send it to the AsyncImage (For reference see the above question contains `xmlParser = [[egsXMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://retrieveurlxml.com/sample.xml"];`

Comment: That's great... Once again thanks a lot for your support. let me try this.